# CKEditor configuration, prefer img tag atrributes over inline style

Tags: html, text-editing

Looking for a way to disable a feature in CKEditor that messes with attributes height and width on my  and converts them into inline styles.

The version of CKEditor is 3.2 and I have access to config files.

Along the same lines is there somewhere an overview (or procedure) for changing the way CKEditor produces html (I'd like to force it to do inline styles; except for images, plus some other changes)

Thank you for taking the time to read this

Comment: Perhaps this would be better for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)?